# ssh to a list of servers and run a command against the same list

Tags: bash

I have a list of servers where I want to ssh to each server in the list, then run a command against the same list of servers, before moving to the next server and running the command through the list again.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -u 9 server; do
    ssh root@$server iperf -c $server -y C >> "/tmp/results.txt"
    done 9< /root/servers.txt
```

I would like the results to show

```
server1 -> server1
server1 -> server2
server1 -> server3
server2 -> server1
server2 -> server2
server2 -> server3
```

but the results show

```
server1 -> server1
server1 -> server2
server1 -> server3
```

*EDIT*

This is what I ended up with:

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVERS=`cat /root/servers.txt`
DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)

for server in $SERVERS; do
    echo "Starting iperf server on $server"
    ssh root@$server nohup iperf -s < /dev/null >> /tmp/log_$DATE.txt 2>&1 &
    sleep 5
    for client in $SERVERS; do
            echo Testing from $client to $server
            ssh root@$client iperf -c $server -y C >> /tmp/results_$DATE.txt
    done
    ssh root@$server pkill -KILL iperf >> /tmp/log_$DATE.txt
done

echo "Test results saved to /tmp/results_$DATE.txt"
```

Comment: Better to put the list of server addresses in an array and loop over the array.

Comment: You can do that with `readarray -t SERVERS < /root/servers.txt`. Then loop with `for server in "${SERVERS[@]}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want all possible 2 length permutations of list of servers. Then you want to run for each pair of servers the test. Nothing simpler.

```
while read -r srv1 srv2; do
    ssh root@"$srv1" iperf -c "$srv2" -y C >> "/tmp/results.txt"
done < <(
    while read -r line; do
        sed 's/$/ '"$line"'/' /root/servers.txt
    done < /root/servers.txt
)
```

1. First the `<( .. )` part. For each line in file the sed is run. The sed's adds the  line to the end of the file and outputs it. Thus we get all possible pairs of servers.
2. For each pair, tun the perf command.
3. We can also do a `|` redirection.

```
while read -r line; do
     sed 's/$/ '"$line"'/' /root/servers.txt
done < /root/servers.txt |
while read -r srv1 srv2; do
    ssh root@"$srv1" iperf -c "$srv2" -y C >> "/tmp/results.txt"
done
```

Comment: I recommend to append `< /dev/tty` to your ssh command. Otherwise a remote program which reads from stdin will read the input with the server names from the outer loop. Could be as easy as one server spawning the password prompt (because key based auth failed for some reason). This server would consume the whole remaining list of servers.

Comment: Or use dedicated file descriptor like OP did with `9<`.

Comment: Thanks!  From your comment I ended up adding the second variable which resolved the issue.